# how to call href function with arugments one by one in jwplayer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jwplayer

I want jwplayer to load list of href one by one,I have list of href with a function called in it,how to auto trigger href link function with parameter i used and pass to JavaScript. I have included my code below.

```
<html>
<head>
//Add jwplayer script
</head>
<body>
<div id='VideoPlayer'>Loading the player ...</div>
<ul id="myList">
<li><a href="#" onclick="show_alert('sample video1','image1')">Test</a>
<li><a href="#" onclick="show_alert('sample video2','image2')">Test1</a>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_alert(my_string,s)
{
var playerInstance = jwplayer('VideoPlayer');
playerInstance.setup({
file: my_string,
image: s,
title: 'My Cool Video',
primary: 'html5',
width: 640,
height: 480
});
}
[].forEach.bind(document.querySelectorAll("#myList li a"),function(itm){
itm.click();
})(); </script></body></html>
```

Comment: What's the expected behavior that you are trying to achieve? Could it be accomplished using a playlist: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference#playlist or feed: https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1406722-external-playlists-and-feeds?

Comment: I want my player to play list of video link's provided without playlist, Without on-click task.
https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1480872-example-creating-an-html-playlist Above link supports with onclick, When I set on ready function to load it loads last video from provided link.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to implement the JavaScript load behavior within the setup config. Try separating these behaviors. For example:

```
<body>

<div id="VideoPlayer"></div>

<ul>
<li><a href="javascript:loadVideo('SampleVideo1.mp4','SampleImage1.jpg')">Video 1</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:loadVideo('SampleVideo2.mp4','SampleImage2.jpg')">Video 2</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:loadVideo('SampleVideo3.mp4','SampleImage3.jpg')">Video 3</a></li>
</ul>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var playerInstance = jwplayer("VideoPlayer");
    playerInstance.setup({
        file: 'SampleVideo.mp4',
        image: 'SampleImage.jpg',
        title: 'My Cool Video',
        primary: 'html5',
        width: 640,
        height: 480
    });

  function loadVideo(myFile,myImage) { 
    playerInstance.load([{
      file: my_string,
      image: s,
    }]);
    playerInstance.play();
  };
</script>


</body>
```

Comment: Its works fine with on-click function but i want my player start to load list of href one by one without on-click .